# Tensorflow warning: two cells provided to MultiRNNCell are the same object

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have been consistently receiving the following warning while executing tensorflow scripts

> WARNING:tensorflow:At least two cells provided to MultiRNNCell are the
>   same object and will share weights.

```
lstm_layer=rnn.LSTMBlockCell(num_units,forget_bias=1)
lstm_layer=rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_layer, output_keep_prob=output_keep_prob)
stacked_lstm = rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_layer] * num_layers)
outputs,_=rnn.static_rnn(stacked_lstm,input,dtype="float32")
```

However, the RNNs in question appear to be running fine, and are making accurate predictions.

What are the implications in relation to the warning message? Can it be safely ignored? If it is potential serious, how might its impact be evaluated?

Comment: Probably RNNCell references are the same (they are the same object). Can you put relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `[lstm_layer] * num_layers` to create multiple RNN layers that actually refer to a same object in python. This usage is normal in some versions of tensorflow, and some versions will report errors.

As the warning says, since all RNN layers are the same object, their weights will remain the same. All errors are fed back to an RNN layer. It is equivalent to reducing the parameters of the model and reducing the complexity of the model.

If you want to create multiple different RNN layers and complex models, you can use the following usage. The effectiveness evaluation of these two different methods depends on the specific application scenarios and results. If your model results are good enough, more complex models don't make much sense.

```
rnn_layers = []
for _ in range(num_layers):
    lstm_layer = rnn.LSTMBlockCell(num_units, forget_bias=1)
    lstm_layer = rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_layer, output_keep_prob=output_keep_prob)
    rnn_layers.append(lstm_layer)

stacked_lstm = rnn.MultiRNNCell(rnn_layers)
```